# How can I make the attribute of an object shows up in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the MVC in Rails. I have a very stupid problem, but I can't get make it works....I have a model object Controls, and Controls have three attributes (level,day => DateTime, period). The periods are these ones: @@periods= ['pre-breakfast','post-breakfast','pre-lunch','post-lunch','afternoon','pre-dinner','post-dinner']. My problem is that when I create a new control and I print it on my page, the period it doesn't show up but a number from 1 to 7 does. This is my code

The code of the view

## Controls

```
<ul>
<% @controls.each do |control| %>
    <li><%= "Blood Sugar Control:" + control.level.to_s + " - " + control.period.to_s + " - " + control.day.to_s %></li>
    <%= link_to "Delete", control_path(control.id), method:'delete', data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
    <%= link_to "edit", edit_control_path(control)%>
</ul>
<% end %>
</div>
```

This is the code of the controller

```
def months
    @user= current_user
    @controls= @user.controls.order_by_date
end
```

This is the code of the form

```
<%= form_for @control, :html => {:class => 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
    <p class="new_control_text">New Control</p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <%= f.label :level, class: "sr-only", for: "exampleInputEmail2" %>

          <%= f.number_field :level, class: "form-control", id: "exampleInputEmail2", placeholder: "Enter level" %>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group container">
        <div class="row datetimeselect">
            <div class='col-sm-12'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>

                        <%= f.text_field :day, default: DateTime.current, :class => 'form-control' %>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>

    <div class="select_period">
       <%= f.select :period, options_for_select([['pre-breakfast'], ['post-breakfast'],['pre-lunch'],['post-lunch'],['afternoon'],['pre-dinner'],['post-dinner']]), {}, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>      

      <%= f.submit "Save", type:"submit", class: "btn btn-default button-save" %>

<% end %>
```

And this is the code of the model

```
def get_day
    calendar_day = DateTime.new(day.year, day.month, day.day)
    calendar_day
end

def self.order_by_date
    @controls = Control.all.sort_by { |control| [control.get_day, control.period]}
end
```

I hope you can help me to understand why the control.period it doesn't show up. Thank you

Comment: If you look in the database after you create a control object through the form, is the period set correctly there?

Comment: If I look in db>migrate>createControls there are no objects, just the attributes of that object (:level, :day, :period) But the controls are printed where I want.

Comment: Are you using an `enum` in your Controls model?

Comment: Try starting the console (`rails console`) in a new terminal window and type `Control.last` after you create a new control

Comment: Ok. I don't know how but problem solved. Thank you¡¡